# Boot fails with ext4 filesystem error, unable to log in

Tags: release-freya, boot

I have a Horize P370M laptop that I installed elementary OS Freya over the top of a Luna install around two months ago.  This morning, when trying to boot in from Grub I get the following message and cannot log in:

```
[5.176647] EXT4 fs error (device sda5): ext4_ext_check_inode:479: inode #1310899: comm ureadahead: pblko bad header/extent: invalid magic-magic 0, entries 83, max 4(0), depth 0(0)
```

My Linux foo has failed on this error - is there any way to fix this or is it a rebuild of Freya that is required?

Kind regards

Mark

Answer (score 4):

I did a little bit of a look around and found little that could help.  I returned and ran `fsck` manually and was able to clear the issue!  Yay me!  My Linux Foo did not abandon me...

Comment: It's great you were able to solve your problem yourself, but it would be even greater of you to expand on what you did to solve your problem (How did you run `fsck`? What options, for example? What was the problem you faced exactly?) - to help users facing the same issue and finding your post during their research :)

Comment: I think the cause was bad sectors.But `fsck` fixed them :)